# How to move the content of DIV tag in to right side

Tags: html

I have to move the content of the `div` tag 20 pixels to the right. How can I do this?

```
<div id="1st">
        <h1><font color="red"><i>Step - 1</i></font></h1>
        <img src="images\1.jpg" />
        <h2><font color="red"><b>Dress to impress.</b> </font></h2>
        <p>
            <font color="blue">
                <b>
                    Not only will you look and smell more attractive, taking
                    care of your<br /> grooming shows her that you're mature and capable of important
                    daily tasks. Pay<br /> particular attention to these areas:
                </b>
            </font>
        </p>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <font color="blue">
                    Shower at least once a day. It's probably best to
                    do this in the morning, so you can<br /> start the day feeling fresh and clean.
                    Wash your hair, soap up all over, and rinse<br /> off.
                </font>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

try this in css

```
#1st { float:right; }
```

And After your `<div id="1st></div>"` put this:

```
<div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you want to achieve, but this can be done many ways:

To literally move the div:

```
#1st {
   position: relative;
   left: 20px;
}
```

To give it the appearance of moving, but occupy an extra 20px in width:

```
#1st {
   margin-left: 20px;
}
```

You could also do it this way (it'd also move other inline elements right):

```
#1st {
   margin-right: -20px;
}
```